# Android Market cannot be opened and cannot download any applications

Tags: google-play-store

When I first bought my GT-i5801, I could easily access the Android Market and there was no hassle in downloading any applications I want. But then one time it had a virus or something that doesn't allow the phone to open. Then I had it repaired to a Samsung registered repair shop. Then after it was repaired even a single application cannot be downloaded and that the android market can't even be opened.

So what happened? What can I do with this matter?

Answer (score 5):

The first thing you could try is to clear the Android Market cache and data. This can be done from `Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications -> (All ->) Market -> Clear data`. Note that the "All" tab may not be available on your device, depending on your Android version. If it's not there, then disregard that step.